# OpenCV WarpPerspective - Strong distortion for generated homography

Tags: c++, opencv, homography, perspectivecamera

I'm using OpenCVs "findHomography" to calculate the 3x3 matrix between two images from two different cameras, which have an angel of 90° to each other. After warping one image to appear in the perspective of the other camera, the image is strongly distorted on the right half.

Already found some implementations, which translate the image before warping and translating back right after. Even with this implementation, I am only able to see a "wider" area of the image, but still not usable, because it's heavily distorted. As I suggest, I am not able to fully translate the negative coordinates, because the values for x/y are so high, that the image would get pretty big an unusable.

I am wondering, if there is something like a maximum angle, one could "transform perspective"( as the distortion gets lower with smaller camera angels to each other, like for 45° I am only loosing 1/8 of the image width).

I uploaded some pictures for better visualization. One is the camera pose of both cameras to each other, one the image I get after warping and the third one is the original image from the camera.

Thanks for any ideas or help!

Comment: https://ibb.co/GTD08r3
https://ibb.co/56LtnLL https://ibb.co/87HLkYN

Comment: Please don't use URL shorteners here. They're too dangerous to click, so most readers will (hopefully) not follow those links. Giving you the benefit of the doubt, just inline any images in your question, since questions should be self-contained. Homographies map planes to planes, not 3D scenes to 3D scenes. Since all pixels are effectively flattened onto the starting plane regardless of the distance from the camera of the points in space they represent, there will more distortion in the output the more your image differs from that initial assumed plane.